# Office-js \\ outlook addin : Office.cast.item.toAppointment(Office.context.mailbox.item) returns error

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are currently developping an outlook add-in that needs to lists the email addresses associated with an email or an appointment.

We have no trouble implementing this on the email part but the appointments are a bit more challenging as Office.context.mailbox.item always points to a AppointmentCompose object and when we try to cast-it to an AppointmentRead, it returns the following error :

```
Office.cast.item.toAppointment(Office.context.mailbox.item)
outlook-web-16.01.debug.js:10346 Uncaught Error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: 
Object cannot be converted to the required type.
```

For the record, the object we tried to cast in this case is an already existing appointment

Is this normal behavior ? How can we convert the office.context.mailbox.item to an appointment read ?

Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior. You cannot cast an AppointmentCompose to an AppointmentRead because the supported APIs are different. Depending on the client you are using, opening an existing appointment as an organizer (organizer if you created the appointment) will always be an AppointmentCompose.

If you are interested in listing the email addresses, you should look into using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_5/office.recipients?view=office-js#getasync-options--callback- for requiredAttendees and optionalAttendees like Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.getAsync

Comment: Thank you, we did indeed list the email adresses through the getAsync methods. I think it would be nice if the item object had a method to tell which state he is in (Read or Compose), for now we had to guess it is in compose mode if the organizer propery  is undefined. Also, the trouble with the Compose form is that we have no mean to get the item's Id even if the appointment was already created.

Comment: For detecting Read vs Compose, please don't reply the presence of the organizer API since this will be defined in Compose in the latest versions of Outlook (see item.organizer in [requirement set 1.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/outlook-requirement-set-1.7?context=outlook/context)). You can add a query parameter to the Source Location URLs in the add-in manifest to distinguish between the two entry points.

Comment: To get the item's id in Compose, please use the [item.saveAsync API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#saveasyncoptions-callback), which returns the itemId in the callback.

Comment: Thank you for these precisions ! for the compose mode vs read mode we used the GetIsRead method of the mailbox but as it is not listed in the documentation  we were wondering if it was a valid approach. If not, we will switch to the query parameter as suggested. We did use the saveAsync API to get the itemId but this requires to upgrade the add-ins privilege to ReadWrite and it's a bit a pitty that we just cant have the itemId without forcing a save. Thank you again for your help !